# Equation $x = \varphi(x) + \varphi(x + 1) – 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Does anybody have any ideas how to solve the equation $x = \varphi(x) + \varphi(x + 1) – 1$, where $x$ is a natural number and $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function?

I failed even to figure out whether this equation has finite number of solutions or infinite.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Comment: These are the ones I found: 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 15, 21, 35, 39, 45, 75, 99, 135, 231, 255, 363, 483, 765, 855, 1295, 1599, 2015, 2115, 4335, 6783, 9999

Comment: Using your numbers, I found that this is sequence $A067798$ at $OEIS$

Comment: Where did you find this problem, if I may ask? And if you thought of it yourself, in what context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some more observations, not an answer but too large for a comment.

If $x$ is a prime, then:

$$\varphi(x) + \varphi(x + 1) - 1 = x$$
$$x - 1 + \varphi(x + 1) - 1 = x$$
$$\varphi(x + 1) = 2$$

So we can not have prime $x > 5$. If $x$ is $n^2 - 1$, with even $n$ then:

$$\varphi(x) + \varphi(x + 1) - 1 = x$$
$$\varphi(n^2 - 1) + \varphi(n^2) - 1 = n^2 - 1$$
$$\varphi((n+1)(n-1)) + n\varphi(n) = n^2$$
$$\varphi(n+1)\varphi(n-1) + n\varphi(n) = n^2$$
$$\varphi(n+1)\varphi(n-1) = n(n - \varphi(n))$$

Using this equality I found the following (non-exhaustive) set of numbers:

$$\{3, 15, 35, 99, 255, 483, 1295, 1599, 2115, 9999, 14399, 18495, 53823, 65535, 732735, 1679615, 2559999, 4064255, 18800895, 207359999, 259081215, 930006015, 3943839999, 4294967295, 6024243455, 471606333695\}$$

The last $n$ for which the above equality holds below $10^7$ is $686736$.

Using a similar technique for $n^4-1$ I've found $x = 353473690402815$ as the biggest solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

*Thius is more a comment than anything else.*

As said in comments, using your numbers, I found that this is sequence $A067798$ at $OEIS$.

Continuing the search up to $10^7$, I got the following numbers
$$\{1,2,3,5,9,15,21,35,39,45,75,99,135,231,255,363,483,765,855,1295,1599,2015,2115,43
   35,6783,9999,14399,16095,16599,18495,30495,53823,62799,63455,65535,77615,155319,
   186999,196095,327675,589815,686735,722015,732735,1456719,1679615,2559999,4064255
   \}$$

Comment: A few of those numbers are $n^2-1$.  Some end in $99$ because $n$ is a multiple of $10$.  Some end in $55$ and $15$ for a similar reason.

Comment: @B.Goddard. I noticed this point when I went to OEIS. It is amazing to notice how short is the list. The log plot is interesting.